# Can't catch $_POST/$_GET sent via Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

See @jpossi Answer.

*I am not accepting an answer just yet, so that somebody can shed some light on what might be the problem, although it's far fetched as the original `POST` code is not present.*

Alright, so this worked, I just had to comment out `processData: false`. But since the actual function uses the `POST` method, I tried going back to the original code : `var data = new FormData (  );` keep the `processData: false` and change to `method : 'GET'` and guess what, it worked... I simple got back to the original `POST` code, uncommenting a few lines and commenting out a few lines. what's going on ?

---

Here is the code, it's pretty simple but somehow I am not able to catch the $_POST data sent by the Ajax function. Infact, I am not able to send the correct post data.

Here I tried with `GET` option and here is the result.

```
/**Javascript**/
var data = new FormData (  );
data.append ( 'unique_id',  unique_id  ); // This I checked, it is correct.
$.ajax ( {
    method : 'GET', url : scriptUrl, data : data, cache : false, processData: false, contentType: false, dataType : 'json',
    success : function ( data, textStatus, jqXHR )
    {
        if ( typeof data.error === 'undefined' ) { alert ( data ); }
        else { alert ( 'cccsdsd' ); }
    },
    error : function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
    {
        alert ( textStatus );// This fires with Parseerror.
    }
} );

/**PHP**/
if ( $this->input->get ( 'unique_id' ) ) // I am working with codeigniter.
{
    $data ['message'] = 'My Message';
    echo json_encode ( $data );
}
else 
{
    echo 'Something Else';
}
```

The Ajax never is successful, it always throws the `parseerror`.

The firebug **GET url** turns out like this : `http://localhost/mysite/Cart [object%20FormData]&_=1451738500443`

The response sent by the server is `Something Else`.

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Comment: One thing which is obvious is that if you return `echo 'Something Else';`, this isn't valid JSON notation and so will throw parse error client side

Comment: I see no reference of `$_POST` in your code.

Comment: You method should be `POST` if you're using a formdata object

Comment: @Musa Are you sure about that? OP is explecitely setting `processData: false`, so the data isn't converted to query string

Comment: @Musa `POST` or `GET` same error, I checked it with the `GET` therefore the `GET` code here.

Comment: @StudentX Ok, you have to set `processData: false` and i guess @Musa is correct then

Comment: The parse error is due to the response, the success and the failure response should both be json. Also make sure the server side code checks for post variables.

Comment: use `contentType: false`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.ajax() expected as "data": PlainObject or String or Array

FormData can be used for POST-Requests. (This is handled by Browsers, not jQuery). FormData can not be converted to a GET-String, as it is intended to handle cases like File-Uploads.

You should change data to:

```
var data = {'unique_id': unique_id};
```

or change from GET to POST

or (as of comments) change processData to true

Comment: you can use formdata in jquery ajax

Comment: No you can send form data directly to data its valid i tried it.. error may be because of `parser`.

Comment: Alright, so this worked, I just had to comment out `processData: false`. But since the actual function uses the `POST` method, I tried going back to the original code : `var data = new FormData (  );` keep the `processData: false` and change to `method : 'GET'` and guess what, it worked... I simple got back to the original `POST` code, uncommenting a few lines and commenting out a few lines. what's going on ? I

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
var data = new FormData (  );
data.append ( 'unique_id',  unique_id  ); // This I checked, it is correct.
```

just use

```
var data = { unique_id : unique_id };
```

Where

```
var data = { index_name : index_value };
```